# Why does the Chrome DevTools Responsive viewport think it's 980px wide?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, responsive-design

I've used Chrome DevTools to resize the viewport to 480px wide, as shown below.

I'm using bootstrap's grid layout, so I have a `div.container` that I'm using, as shown in the bottom left. When I hover over it, I see chrome has that particular `div` marked as width `750px` (and the whole `body` is `980px`), even though I clearly have the screen set at a smaller resolution. Even the ruler at the top shows it is 480px wide.

For further confirmation, you can see the media query that says the width of 750px should only be set at higher resolutions (min 768px), so the viewport is assuming it's a higher width than it is.

Am I mis-understanding how the responsive feature is used?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What value you have in metadata of viewport?

Comment: Is that the `<meta name="viewport" ..>` tag? I checked the `<head>` and didn't see anything with that name, so I'm guessing it uses a default value?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

*For accepting answer*

As stated in comments: you are missing `meta` tag with viewport that is required for media-queries to take effect.

Comment: @rinogo same here. The lack of information on why that `980px` min-width is taking effect is maddening! Thank heavens for Google + StackOverflow.

Answer (score 33):

As answered above, adding a metatag in html header will resolve the issue. 
Below is the  viewport element, which should be included in all your web pages

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: More info about viewport and its params on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).